# xsl: trying to use a "not" in an xsl:when/following-sibling statement

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to find situations where a heading tag (head1) is not followed by a body tag.

Here's a snippet of what I'd be searching for, "head1" followed by "body":

```
<title role="head1">Third-Party Notices and/or Licenses</title>
<para role="body">Required notices for open source software products or components used by Cloud are identified in the following table along with the applicable licensing information.</para>
```

And here's the code I'm trying (the empty head1 code works fine):

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='ahead1']">
    <xsl:variable name="elementValue">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="title.text.only" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$elementValue = ''">
            <xsl:message>ERROR: Encountered an head 1 paragraph with no text content.</xsl:message>
            <xsl:call-template name="revealDocPosition"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Code to check to see that a head1 is directly followed by a body tag -->
        <xsl:when test="[$elementValue]and not[following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody]]"> 
        <!-- <xsl:when test="not[$elementValue][following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody]]"> -->
            <xsl:message>ERROR: Encountered an atg head 1 paragraph that was not follwed by an atgbody.</xsl:message>
            <xsl:call-template name="revealDocPosition"/>
        </xsl:when>
```

It fails in my build because it doesn't like the syntax:

```
 [java] Error at xsl:when on line 30 column 84 of headings.xsl:
 [java]   XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 30 in {[$}:
 [java]     Unexpected token "[" in path expression
 [java] Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

I've tried different syntax and it either fails, or run and doesn't find the error. 
Ideas?

Comment: I suggest that you read a tutorial on XPath first: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) may give you some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The square braces are a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates), and are used to filter items that do not evaluate to true when the predicate filter is applied.

The expression `[$elementValue]` has nothing to test and filter on.

Assuming that you are attempting to test whether `$elementValue` is "truthy" and has content, you need to move it outside of the predicate and just test the variable.

The expression `not[following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody]]` is testing whether there is a child element named `not` and applying a predicate filter, which will never match since you don't have any `not` elements - so this test will never be true. You need to change `[]` to `()` in order to invoke the `not()` function.

```
<xsl:when test="$elementValue and not(following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody])">
```

Comment: This code runs without error, but never finds the situation I'm looking for (head1 NOT followed by a body tag), that is: for every head1, if the next tag is not atgbody, output:    

`<xsl:when test="$elementValue and not[following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody]]"> 
    <xsl:message>ERROR: Encountered an atg head 1 paragraph that was not followed by an atgbody.</xsl:message>
    <xsl:call-template name="revealDocPosition"/>
    <xsl:comment>This is the location of the atghead1 paragraph that was NOT followed with an atgbody tag.</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:when>`

Comment: I just noticed that you had square braces in front of the `not()`. The way that was written, it was looking for a child element named `not` and testing whether it's first following-sibling was an `atgbody` element (which would never happen). Change the square braces to parenthesis, so that you are negating the test for the following-sibling.

Answer (score 0):

```
test="[$elementValue]and not[following-sibling::*[1][self::atgbody]]"
```

You seem to be making this up as you go along. Guessing the syntax isn't going to get you anywhere.

I don't know what's in the variable `$elementValue` because you haven't shown enough of your code. Your code refers to an `atgBody` element which doesn't appear in your source document snippet, and the match pattern also refers to nodes that aren't in your source snippet. This means it's difficult to see what your code is trying to achieve and therefore to tell you exactly where it's wrong.

The syntax error is that `[$elementValue]` isn't a legal expression. Without knowing what you thought it might mean, it's impossible to tell you how to correct it.